# JQuery hide/show function stops working when I put all my components together

Tags: jquery, html-lists

My project has to do with color keying video.  I'm using an UL for navitagion between screens where I fine tune the key, and to hide/show a div where  I'm using a slider to change the number of colors that are keyed out.
All of these things work great separately.  But when I try to get them to all work on the same page, the hide/show stops working. I've tried taking it apart and putting it back together a piece at a time, but I always get stuck at this point.  The code is below.

```
    <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="videoSetup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FGSlider/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="FGSlider/css/ui.slider.extras.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /*body {font-size: 62.5%; font-family:"Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }*/
        fieldset { border:0; margin: 6em; height: 12em;}    
        label {font-weight: normal; float: left; margin-right: .5em; font-size: 1.1em;}
        select {margin-right: 1em; float: left;}
        .ui-slider {
    clear: both;
    top: 5em;
}

.wrap-slider {
    padding: 50px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    display: none;
}

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>


<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
  <header id="top" class="fluid"> 

    <!--  <div id="container">
    <video autoplay id="videoElement">

    </video>
</div>--> 
    <!--from Jeff Burtoft-->
    <div class="row">
      <!--<div class="span5">-->
        <video id="videoElement" controls> 

        </video>
        <canvas id="hiddenCanvas" width="640" height="386"></canvas>
    <!-- </div>
     <div class="span5">-->
        <canvas id="displayCanvas" width="640" height="386"></canvas>
     <!--</div>-->
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
<script src="vidCamAccess.js"></script> 
<script src="eyedropper.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="FGSlider/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FGSlider/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="FGSlider/js/selectToUISlider.jQuery.js"></script>

     <!--jQuery UI theme switcher -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ui.jquery.com/applications/themeroller/themeswitchertool/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(function(){ $('<div style="position: absolute; right: 20px; margin-top: -40px" />').appendTo('body').themeswitcher({onSelect: function(){ setTimeout(fixToolTipColor, 800); }}); });
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");
var hiddenCanvas = document.getElementById("hiddenCanvas");
var displayCanvas = document.getElementById("displayCanvas");
var hiddenContext = hiddenCanvas.getContext ("2d");
var displayContext = displayCanvas.getContext ("2d");

videoElement.addEventListener('play', function(){runAnalysis();});

var runAnalysis = function(){
     if(videoElement.paused || videoElement.ended){
      return
}
    frameConversion();
    if(window.requestAnimationFrame){
    requestAnimationFrame(runAnalysis);
    }
    else{
    setTimeout(runAnalysis,0);
    }
     };

    var frameConversion = function(){

    hiddenContext.drawImage(videoElement,0,0,videoElement.videoWidth, videoElement.videoHeight);

    var frame = hiddenContext.getImageData(0,0,videoElement.videoWidth, videoElement.videoHeight);

    var length = frame.data.length;
    for (var i =0; i <length; i++){
        var r = frame.data [i*4+ 0];
    var g = frame.data [i*4 + 1];
    var b = frame.data [i*4 + 2];
    var p = window.$vars.rgbvalue;
    //if(p > 0)  {alert ("rgbvalue:" + p [0] + "," + p[1] + "," + p[2])};

   /* if(g > 110 && g < 200 && r < 190 && r > 100 && b < 200 && b > 110){  
    frame.data[i*4+ 3] = 0; */

    if(g > p[0]-15 && g < p[0]+15 
    && r > p[1]-15 && r < p[1]+15 
    && b > p[2]-15 && b < p[2]+15){
    frame.data[i*4+ 3] = 0;
    } 
        }
    displayContext.putImageData(frame, 0, 0);
    return
    };

    </script> 

<!--end jeff's code-->

<div class="wrap-slider">
<p> Adjust the red, green and blue components separately to adjust the key.</p>
<p>RED</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            //demo 1
            var abc = $('select#speed').selectToUISlider().next();

            fixToolTipColor();
        });
        //purely for theme-switching demo... ignore this unless you're using a theme switcher
        //quick function for tooltip color match
        function fixToolTipColor(){
            //grab the bg color from the tooltip content - set top border of pointer to same
            $('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').each(function(){
                var bWidth = $('.ui-tooltip-pointer-down-inner').css('borderTopWidth');
                var bColor = $(this).parents('.ui-slider-tooltip').css('backgroundColor')
                $(this).css('border-top', bWidth+' solid '+bColor);
            }); 
        }
    </script>


    <form action="#">
        <!-- demo 1 -->
        <fieldset>
            <label for="speed">Add How many colors to key?</label>
            <select name="speed" id="speed">
            <option value="0" selected="selected" >0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3" >3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
               <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>


    </form>

</div>
<p class="instructions fluid">Find a solid colored wall and stand facing away from it about 2 ft. away. The lighting on the wall needs to be as even as possible. Blue or green works best, but it must be a different color than your clothes.    Select your FRONT FACING camera if you're doing this by yourself. Or find a friend to help.</p>
<nav id="menuSystem" class="fluid">
  <ul id="menus" class="fluid fluidList">
    <li class="fluid menuItem zeroMargin_tablet zeroMargin_desktop">Select Key Color</li>
    <li class="fluid menuItem" id="adjustKey">Adjust Key</li>
    <li class="fluid menuItem">Toggle View</li>
    <li class="fluid menuItem">Home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</header>
</div>
</body>
<script>

$(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.wrap-slider').hide();
    });
    $('#adjustKey').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('.wrap-slider').toggle();
    });
    $('.wrap-slider').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wrap-slider').hide();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what Developer Tools are for. Use F12, set breakpoints in appropriate places in the code to see why they're not working. Expecting us to review 200 lines of code and find your bugs is a bit much.

Comment: At the very least you're loading two different versions of jQuery

Comment: I know its obtuse.  It happens when I get stuck. I see the duplicates now, and I'm working on that.  Thanks for looking, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Near the top of the code you're loading the latest jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Further down, as part of the FGSlider installation you're loading jQuery 1.3.2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FGSlider/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

These will probably interfere with each other. At the very least the 1.3.2 version is likely to take precedence, and you'll lose a lot of functionality that might affect later code.

You're loading a number of 3rd-party libraries. Are you sure that these aren't interfering with each other? Seek out the lateste version of each - hopefully the later versions will be cleaner than the earlier ones.

Then at the bottom you appear to be installing a set of click handlers before running `$(document).ready()`. It's likely that the script is attempting to install the click handlers before the DOM is ready

Change the trailing script to:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.wrap-slider').hide();


// wrap this inside your $(document).ready() code.
$(function () {
  $(document).click(function () {
    $('.wrap-slider').hide();
  });
  $('#adjustKey').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.wrap-slider').toggle();
  });
  $('.wrap-slider').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
});

});
</script>
```

I can't promise that that's all that's wrong, but it's a start.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll try these suggestions.  I'm getting code from many different sources on this page, and trying to make it work together. That's why I have duplicate libraries.